# How much approximate gameplay is there in the full version of Limbo?

Tags: limbo

I went through the demo of Limbo and it looks like a pretty cool game. I'm thinking about purchasing it, but I've heard criticism that it is very short, and the small number of achievements seems to reinforce that idea.

Approximately how long does it take to play through the entire game?

Comment: [Does it really matter?](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2010/08/more-in-the-bottle-the-dubious-value-of-game-length.ars)

Comment: @badp value = time*enjoyment/cost, he already knows enjoyment (from the demo) and he can look up cost, so what he really wants is time to complete this equation.  I think its a very worthwhile question.

Comment: @tzenes, I'm just linking to the ongoing discussion in the gaming industry about game length and value.

Comment: ah, well then thank you for your contribution, it was a great read and I really enjoyed it.

Comment: @badp He wouldn't ask if it didn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an achievement for completing the game in one sitting, with 5 deaths or less, so I would think that for the standard player, it shouldn't be very long.  I completed it in one sitting myself, and it took me between 2 and 3 hours.  for 1,200 points, I'd expected a bit more, but the atmosphere and ambiance in the game mostly made up for my feelings of being shortchanged.

Comment: Thanks. That combined with the fact that it doesn't seem to have much re playability makes me hesitant to drop $20 on it. However, the atmosphere is incredible. Reminds me a lot of braid in that respect.

Comment: Additionally, aside from the eggs for achievements, there are also other eggs to find that go towards the 111% maximum completion score. These eggs are harder to find, as there are no clues for them.

Comment: @JohnFx - If you're really into 'art house' style games like _Braid_, then I think _Limbo_ would probably be worth the $20 to you, although that's really up to you.

Comment: @JohnFX: $20?  Isn't it $15?

Comment: @jamesdlin: Well, 1400 Microsoft points costs $20.   Limbo costs 1200 points, so it's probably closer to $20 then $15.

Comment: Especially since you can't buy in 1200 point blocks (as far as I know)

Comment: @GnomeSlice: Uh, what?  $20US should buy 1600 points, not 1400.  $5 for every 400 points means that a 1200 point game costs $15.

Comment: @JohnFX: A fair point, but you don't foresee ever purchasing anything else?

Comment: FYI: I did eventually purchase and play-through it in about 3.5 hours. All in all, it was probably worth it. My only complaint is that the minimalistic nature of the game made most of the puzzles very easy to solve.

Comment: @ jamesdlin: Well I don't know about the states, some to think of it, but you can't buy 1600 point blocks in Canada.  If that's not true for the states, then please disregard my comments.  :)

Comment: ^ come to think of it*.  Mistype.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [Gamastutra article](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/29598/Analysis_Limbos_Completion_Time__Whats_in_a_Length.php), about 4 hours, up to 5 or 6 if you get stuck on some of the puzzles.

Comment: That seems a bit high...

Comment: Some sites list even longer times, but that article seemed in line with the consensus. Play length is a subjective description anyway - completely depends on the player.

Answer (score 3):

I don't generally speak in hours, as it's really not a good metric in my opinion. (Of course, when it comes to puzzle games, throw every metric out the window because everyone plays differently.)

Generally speaking, the demo is approximately 1/6th the full game. Bearing in mind that the puzzles only get harder, so YMMV in terms of how long it takes you to solve a particular one. God knows I took a lot longer for some…

Comment: I like the comparison of game length to the demo length - I think it gives a good feel for the amount of gameplay you get relative to how you play the game.